# How are graphical passwords stored in computer systems?

Tags: security, passwords, computer-science

How are graphical passwords stored in computer systems?
How does the computer know whether the password entered by user is correct or incorrect?

Comment: What's a graphical password ?

Comment: interesting, graphical password.

Comment: It is another means of authentication, it is like alphanumeric passwords but instead of using letters and numbers. You use images. Abit like Windows 8 Picture Password

Comment: I just need to know how it is stored in computers....encryption, hashing, all of that...

Comment: I expect he means a **captcha**. I believe captcha are created by low cost labour in developing countries; the same low cost labour in developing countries that captures automated responses to captchas, curiously enough.

Comment: No I don't mean captcha....have a look at Windows 8 Picture Password

Comment: I don't have Windows 8 yet. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: It is okay, however, do you know how passwords are generally stored in computer systems :)

Comment: @user1958596: If there even *is* a hash, since there has to be tolerance to error, the hash needs to map "similar" inputs to the exact same outputs, so it's not a traditional one-to-one hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled and found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/12/16/signing-in-with-a-picture-password.aspx). Give it a read, it looks like it answers some of the questions you may have (how is the image broken down, whatnot). From there, it should be simpler to extrapolate how it's stored.

As a note, to clarify, this is a gesture-based signon, similar to what Apple has used on some iPhone lockscreens (but with an image overlay).